# Access Couchdb's Futon using an Ubuntu install from Digital Ocean

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, digital-ocean, couchdb-futon

**Disclaimer:**

I am very new to Ubuntu. I have little linux experience, but I might be missing something simple.

**Description:**

I have just purchased a Droplet from `Digitalocean` and installed Ubuntu on it. I am attempting to use `CouchDB 1.6.1`. I have followed both of these guides, [Guide #1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-couchdb-and-futon-on-ubuntu-12-04) and [Guide #2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-couchdb-from-source-on-an-ubuntu-13-04-x64-vps) which has proved fruitful in installing `CouchDb`. This is evidenced by the fact that a `curl localhost:5984` on the droplet produces:

```
{"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"**id**","version":"1.6.1", "vendor":     
    {"version":"1.6.1","name":"The Apache Software Foundation"}
}
```

I am edited both the `default.ini` and `local.ini` to listen to all incoming requests from `bind_address: 0.0.0.0` which I have read that accepts any `ip`.

To prove that, I run this command:

```
netstat -tapen | grep ":5984"
```

Which produces:

```
tcp      0      0  127.0.0.1:5984        0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN   0   455066     8525/ssh
```

**Problem:**

When I navigate to `my_droplet_ip:5984/_utils` nothing shows up in the browser with Chrome returning a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Internally you seem to have done everything right. Your tests were all locally executed. What is the result when you test from remote?

Comment: Also, have you restarted the CouchDB after you have edited the local.ini?

Comment: I have restarted the couchdb service many times using `service couchdb restart`. @llabball, can you explain to me what you mean by testing it remote?

Comment: Your netstat result shows the local ip `127.0.0.1`. I have assumed you have executed the command locally. "Find another machine connected to the internet and execute the netstat test from there" - was what i  have wanted to express

Comment: I executed that command on the droplet. I am not too sure how I could `netstat` from another PC that isn't the droplet. Sorry, new to this.

Comment: Netstat is a command that you can execute on almost any other linux. Do you have access to an own installation of ubuntu perhaps?

Comment: Oh, so replicate my environment on another VM. I can't do that sadly as I don't have one available.